# Sigmoidal function with arbitrary flex

Tags: functions

I'm searching for a function $f(x):[0,1]\mapsto [0, 1]$ with the following properties
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
f(0)=1 \\
f(1)=0 
\end{aligned}
\qquad
\begin{aligned}
\dot{f}(0)=0 \\
\dot{f}(1)=0 
\end{aligned}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $\dot{f}(x)\triangleq\frac{\text{d}f(x)}{\text{d}x}$. For example, the Gaussian "semi-pulse"
\begin{equation*}
f(x)\triangleq\exp\left[-\left(\frac{x}{0.4}\right)^2\right]
\end{equation*}
is a good approximation of what I'm searching for. However, this solution does not satisfy me because:

1. the terminal conditions $f(1)=0$ and $\dot{f}(1)=0$ hold only with a certain approximation;
2. I have no control in the position of the flex point.

I'm trying different types of [sigmoidal functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function#Examples) and I'm struggling to find a function that satisfies *exactly* $(1)$ and, at the same time, gives me the possibility to move the flex point in $[0,1]$.
Hence, I would like to have a hand to understand if the problem that I'm facing is impossible (or not) to be solved. If it is not impossible, I would like to have an example of $f(x)$ satisfying my requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements are really easy to implement with polynomials. Consider a cubic polynomial $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$. Your four requirements just translate to four equations that you can solve.

If you want to further control the flex point, use a quartic polynomial and specify the flex point as the zeropoint of the second derivative, for example $f''(1/3) = 0$. You can solve this equation to get what you want. This is generally called [**Hermite interpolation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_interpolation).

Perhaps you would like all the derivatives to be zero at the boundary, instead of just the first. You can do that with bump functions.

Comment: I forgot to say that $x=0$ and $x=1$ have to be the maximum and the minimum. Polynomials do not satisfy these additional requirements. On the other hand, bump functions work like a charm, so thank you so much!

Comment: @matteogost The cubic example does satisfy that, what do you mean? In general, since you have control over the derivatives, the max/minimum is relatively easy to control (if you don't have too many datapoints to interpolate)

Comment: I need to control the flex point, we can do it with polynomials of order 4. However, for some values of the flex point the curve can get value larger than $f(0)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the four-parameters logistic curve defined by
$$f(x) = A + \frac{D-A}{\Bigl(1+\exp\bigl(B(C-x)\bigr)\Bigr)}$$
with $B>0$. Then:

- $A$ is the value of the horizontal asymptote when $x \to -\infty$;
- $D$ is the value of the horizontal asymptote when $x \to +\infty$;
- $B$ describes how rapidly the curve makes its transition between the two
  asymptotes;
- $C$ is a location parameter, it is the value of $x$ for which the
  corresponding value $f(x)$ is the midpoint between the two asymptotes, and
  the curve has its inflection point at $x = C$.